# Django: How to update an image without refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, ajax

I am working in Djnago and I want to update an image without reloading or refreshing the page. I have used Ajax for get method to receive the image, and it is working too but to see the new image, I have to refresh the page. This image is generated by the `bfs_view` method in the `views.py` file. At first, it receives an input as a text and then generates a new image according to the given input.

The `views.py` file:

```
# def product_create_view(request):
def bfs_view(request):
    form = BFSForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        form = BFSForm()
    try:
        image_url_info = None
        num_states_explored = None
        final_solution = None

        text_file = open("BFS\outputs\maze.txt", "w")
        field_name = 'description'
        input_value = BFS.objects.latest('id')

        field_object = BFS._meta.get_field(field_name)
        field_value = field_object.value_from_object(input_value)


        field_string_value = str(field_value).split("\n")

        text_file.writelines(field_string_value)
        text_file.close()

        m = Maze("BFS\outputs\maze.txt")
        print("Maze:")
        m.print()
        print("Solving...")
        m.solve()
        print("States Explored:", m.num_explored)
        print("Solution:")
        m.print()

        m.output_image("BFS\outputs\maze.png", show_explored=True)
        m.output_image("static/search/bfs/maze.png", show_explored=True)

        image_url_info = "/../../../static/search/bfs/maze.png"
        num_states_explored = m.num_explored
        
        # final_solution = ''.join(m.end_result)
        final_solution = str(''.join(m.end_result))
        print(''.join(m.end_result))
        get_bfs_image_view(request)

        # BFS.objects.latest('id').delete()
    except:
        print("BFS ERROR: Error in the try session of BFS in view.py")

    context = {
        'form': form, 'image_url': image_url_info, 'states_explored': num_states_explored, 
        'solution': final_solution}

    return render(request, "BFS/bfs.html", context)


def post_bfs_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST" and request.is_ajax():
        bfs_view(request)
        return JsonResponse({"success":True}, status=200)
    return JsonResponse({"success":False}, status=400)


def get_bfs_view(request):
    if request.method == "GET" and request.is_ajax():
        try:
            image_url_info = None
            num_states_explored = None
            final_solution = None

            text_file = open("BFS\outputs\maze.txt", "w")
            field_name = 'description'
            input_value = BFS.objects.latest('id')

            field_object = BFS._meta.get_field(field_name)
            field_value = field_object.value_from_object(input_value)


            field_string_value = str(field_value).split("\n")

            text_file.writelines(field_string_value)
            text_file.close()

            m = Maze("BFS\outputs\maze.txt")
            print("Maze:")
            m.print()
            print("Solving...")
            m.solve()
            print("States Explored:", m.num_explored)
            print("Solution:")
            m.print()

            m.output_image("static/search/bfs/maze.png", show_explored=True)
            image_url_info = "/../../../static/search/bfs/maze.png"
            
            # final_solution = ''.join(m.end_result)
            final_solution = str(''.join(m.end_result))
            print(''.join(m.end_result))
            # bfs_view(request)

            # BFS.objects.latest('id').delete()
            bfs_view(request)
        except:
            print("BFS ERROR: Error in the try session of BFS in view.py")
    return HttpResponse(final_solution)


def get_bfs_image_view(request):
    if request.method == "GET" and request.is_ajax():
        try:
            image_url_info = "/../../../static/search/bfs/maze.png"

        except:
            print("BFS ERROR: Error in the try session of BFS in view.py")
    return HttpResponse(image_url_info)
```

The view function that I used to update the image:

```
def get_bfs_image_view(request):
    if request.method == "GET" and request.is_ajax():
        try:
            image_url_info = "/../../../static/search/bfs/maze.png"

        except:
            print("BFS ERROR: Error in the try session of BFS in view.py")
    return HttpResponse(image_url_info)
```

The main `bfs.html` file:

```
<form id = "contactForm" method='POST' >{% csrf_token %}
   {{ form.as_p }}
   <input type='submit' value='Search' class="submit-btn poppins"/>
</form>

  <pre><span id="myText"></span></pre>
  <div id="myimage"></div>
```

The ajax that I used:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#contactForm").submit(function(e){
        // prevent from normal form behaviour

        e.preventDefault();
        // serialize the form data

        var serializedData = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url :  "{% url 'BFS:contact_submit' %}",
            data : serializedData,

            success : function(response){
                //reset the form after successful submit
                $("#contactForm")[0].reset();

                // This will then call for the get request to update the id "myText"
                live_update();
                live_image_update();
            },

            error : function(response){
               console.log(response)
            }
       });
   });

   function live_update(){
       $.ajax({
           url: "{% url 'BFS:get_user_info' %}",
           type: 'get', // This is the default though, you don't actually need to always mention it

           success: function(data) {
               var number = data;
               document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML = number;
               $("#myText").hide();
                $("#myText").html(data);
                $("#myText").fadeIn(1000);
           },

           error: function() {
               alert('Got an error dude');
           }
      });
   }

   function live_image_update(){
       $.ajax({
           url: "{% url 'BFS:get_bfs_image_info' %}",
           type: 'get', // This is the default though, you don't actually need to always mention it

           success: function(data) {
            $('#myimage').html('<img src="/../../../static/search/bfs/maze.png" />');
           },

           error: function() {
               alert('Got an error dude');
           }
      });
   }
});

</script>
```

The ajax that I used to update the image:

```
function live_image_update(){
       $.ajax({
           url: "{% url 'BFS:get_bfs_image_info' %}",
           type: 'get', // This is the default though, you don't actually need to always mention it

           success: function(data) {
            $('#myimage').html('<img src="/../../../static/search/bfs/maze.png" />');
           },

           error: function() {
               alert('Got an error dude');
           }
      });
   }
});
```

The `urls.py` views:

```
app_name = 'BFS'

urlpatterns = [
    path('bfs/', bfs_view),
    path('ajax/contact', post_bfs_view, name ='contact_submit'),
    path('ajax/get_user_info', get_bfs_view, name = 'get_user_info'),
    path('ajax/get_bfs_image_info', get_bfs_image_view, name = 'get_bfs_image_info'),
]
```

The `models.py` file:

```
class BFS(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description
```

The `forms.py` file:

```
from django import forms
from .models import BFS

class BFSForm(forms.ModelForm):
    description = forms.CharField(
                        required=False, 
                        label=False,
                        widget=forms.Textarea(
                                attrs={
                                    'id': 'TA1',
                                    'rows': '10vh',
                                    'cols': '8vw',
                                    'placeholder': 'Enter Your Map Here',
                                    'class': 'textfield-style',
                                    'style': 'max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;outline: none; border: none; background-color: white; width: 100%; padding: 12px 20px; margin: 8px 0; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 20px; spellcheck="false";',
                                }
                            )
                        )
    
    class Meta:
        model = BFS
        fields = [
            'description'
        ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BFSForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields:
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs.update({
            'class': 'form-control'})
```

Comment: you may be interested in htmx. https://htmx.org/ See https://dev.to/nicholas_moen/what-i-learned-while-using-django-with-htmx-and-alpine-js-24jg#what-is-htmx for example

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are setting the image URL to the same value each time, and so you are not seeing the replaced image because of client-side caching.

The simplest way to work-around this issue would be to use a different filename for each of the generated images. Another simple might be to adjust the URL so that it is a different request, so if you changed the live_image_update success callback to append a timestamped query string, then you would trigger a new request, and see the new image.

```
function live_image_update(){
   $.ajax({
       url: "{% url 'BFS:get_bfs_image_info' %}",
       type: 'get', // This is the default though, you don't actually need to always mention it

       success: function(data) {
        $('#myimage').html('<img src="/../../../static/search/bfs/maze.png?' + 
          Date.now() + '/>');
       },

       error: function() {
           alert('Got an error dude');
       }
  });
```